# How do I copy my entire website from testing area to webhost without breaking

Tags: git, ssh, lamp, sftp, scp

I do not have git available on my webhost's server, and I really want to use it to track my website development.  The best solution I came up with is to develop locally on my LAMP install at home, then scp all the files to my webhost when I have a working version.

Is there a program/standard method to introduce changes to a website all at once?  The idea is to not have a user see a messed up transitional webpage while the (possibly large) file set is copying over.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The most atomic way to swap out your old codebase with the new would be to copy all of it in a new directory at the same level where your old one is, and then rename both directories, like so:

```
// assuming your working copy is in ~/workingcopy
// and your webserver document root is in /path/to/webroot on server "webhost"
// copy all your files to /path/to/webroot.new:
scp -r ~/workingcopy webhost:/path/to/webroot.new
// then run on the server:
mv /path/to/webroot /path/to/webroot.old && mv /path/to/webroot.new /path/to/webroot
```

Afterwards you can back up or delete your old codebase, still stored as `/path/to/webroot.old`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try using SSH, using WinSCP on windows. (If you're on windows). On linux and mac (I think) you could try using Putty.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in that case, even if you have Git in your web host that will not solve the transition as well.

If you have more privilege in your web host (ssh, for example), you can do that through directory linking (assuming you are in LAMP stack). You do the copy to the new version to a new directory, than just change the directory linking once you have completed the copying , everything is updated in one shot.